# Why Mesh layer is not visible in QGIS map using Jupyter (outside QGIS)?

Tags: pyqgis, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a map in Jupyter from QGIS. I have few vector, raster and mesh layers in QGIS. All I want is to add these layers to the map. I have managed to add the shape files and google map to my map but the mesh layer (which is the mike dfsu file) is not visible. Can anyone share the process of adding mesh layer to the map?

```
import os
import sys
from qgis.gui import QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge, QgsMapCanvas
from qgis.core import*
app=QgsApplication([],True)
app.setPrefixPath("C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.30.0", True)

app.initQgis()
fname=""
project = QgsProject.instance()
project.read(fname)
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Map_Day01")[0]
layer_tree_root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()  
layer_tree_layer = layer_tree_root.findLayer(layer.id())  
layer_is_visible = layer_tree_layer.isVisible()
projectInstance = QgsProject.instance()
layoutmanager = projectInstance.layoutManager()
layout = layoutmanager.layoutByName("Day_1")
map_label = QgsLayoutItemLabel(layout)
layout.removeLayoutItem(map_label)
layout.addLayoutItem(map_label)
map_label.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(1.6, 0.5, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutInches))
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
exporter.exportToImage(r"C:\Users\Day-1.png", QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings() )
```

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, a mesh layer may consist of several scalar or vector dataset groups, and it may also be a temporal layer. To visualize a non-temporal mesh layer with scalar dataset groups, you just need to do as follows:

```
rendererS = yourMeshLayer.rendererSettings()
rendererS.setActiveScalarDatasetGroup(your_scalar_dataset_index)
yourMeshLayer.setRendererSettings(rendererS)
```

If your mesh layer is a temporal layer, you have to firstly set temporal properties and then use a GUI called QgsMeshLayerProperties() to activate the dataset you want to visualize, you may also need a temporal controller to navigate on time axis:

```
yourMeshLayer.setReferenceTime(QDateTime(your_dataset_start_time))
temporalProps = yourMeshLayer.temporalProperties()
navGui = QgsTemporalControllerWidget()
controller = navGui.temporalController()
controller.setTemporalExtents(temporalProps.timeExtent())
controller.setNavigationMode(QgsTemporalNavigationObject.Animated)
controller.setFrameDuration(QgsInterval(0.5,QgsUnitTypes.TemporalMinutes))
controller.setFramesPerSecond(24)
yourMapCanvas.setTemporalController(controller)
propGui = QgsMeshLayerProperties(yourMeshLayer, yourMapCanvas)
propGui.show()
```

On the popup Gui, select the dataset you want to visualize and then click apply:
[image]

---

---

The whole code would be as follows:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import Qt
import sys


# Create a GUI containing a mapCanvas, a layerTreeView and a temporalController
class ExampleApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.proj = QgsProject.instance()
        self.root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()

        # Create a canvas (QGraphicsView) for the app
        self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
        self.canvas.setProject(self.proj)
        self.canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.GlobalColor.white)
        self.canvas.enableAntiAliasing(True)
        self.canvas.setPreviewJobsEnabled(True)

        # Create a dock widget hosting the temporalController
        self.dockController = QgsDockWidget("Temporal Controller", self)
        self.controller = QgsTemporalControllerWidget(self.dockController)
        self.dockController.setWidget(self.controller)
        
        # Create a dock widget hosting the layerTreeView
        self.dockTree = QgsDockWidget("Layer Tree", self)
        self.layerTreeView = QgsLayerTreeView(self.dockTree)
        self.dockTree.setWidget(self.layerTreeView)
        
        # Create a model for the layerTreeView
        self.model = QgsLayerTreeModel(self.root)
        self.model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.Flag.AllowNodeReorder)
        self.model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.Flag.AllowNodeRename)
        self.model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.Flag.AllowNodeChangeVisibility)
        self.model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.Flag.ShowLegend)
        self.layerTreeView.setModel(self.model)

        # Organize the GUIs
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.DockWidgetArea.TopDockWidgetArea,self.dockController)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.DockWidgetArea.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.dockTree)
        
        # Connect temporalController to mapCanvas
        self.canvas.setTemporalController(self.controller.temporalController())
        
        # Connect layerTree to mapCanvas
        self.bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(self.root, self.canvas)
        
        # Connect doubleClicked signal of layerTreeView to show the popup GUI
        self.layerTreeView.doubleClicked.connect(self.showMeshLayerPropsGUI)
        
    def showMeshLayerPropsGUI(self):
        currentLayer = self.layerTreeView.currentLayer()
        if currentLayer is not None and isinstance(currentLayer, QgsMeshLayer):
            self.gui = QgsMeshLayerProperties(currentLayer, self.canvas)
            self.gui.show()


qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
qgs.initQgis()
app = ExampleApp()

# Define Coordinate Renference System
target_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:3857")
source_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:32755")
xform = QgsCoordinateTransform(source_crs, target_crs, app.proj)

# Background Raster Layer
urlWithParams = 'type=xyz&url=https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D&zmax=18&zmin=0&http-header:referer='
myRootLayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams,'myTileLayer','wms')

# Mesh Layer (you may change the example uri to your own)
myMeshLayer = QgsMeshLayer('./data/cairns_fixed_wave.sww','MyMeshLayer','mdal')
if not myMeshLayer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")
else:
    myMeshLayer.setCrs(source_crs)
    myMeshLayer.setOpacity(0.6)
    myMeshLayer.setReferenceTime(QtCore.QDateTime(2023,5,17,0,0,0))

# Add Layers through QgsProject.instance()
app.proj.addMapLayers([myMeshLayer, myRootLayer])
app.proj.setCrs(target_crs)

# Renderer Settings for the Mesh Layer
groupIndex = 1
myRendererSettings = myMeshLayer.rendererSettings() #this function returns a copy of the QgsRendererSetting object
myRendererSettings.setActiveScalarDatasetGroup(groupIndex) #for scalar datasets
myRendererScalarSettings = myRendererSettings.scalarSettings(groupIndex)
myRendererSettings.setScalarSettings(groupIndex, myRendererScalarSettings)
myMeshLayer.setRendererSettings(myRendererSettings)

# Temporal Controller Settings
temporalController:QgsTemporalNavigationObject = app.canvas.temporalController()
temporalController.setTemporalExtents(myMeshLayer.temporalProperties().timeExtent())
temporalController.setNavigationMode(QgsTemporalNavigationObject.NavigationMode.Animated)
temporalController.setFrameDuration(QgsInterval(0.5, QgsUnitTypes.TemporalUnit.TemporalMinutes))
temporalController.setFramesPerSecond(24)

# Map Canvas Settings
app.canvas.setDestinationCrs(target_crs)
app.canvas.setExtent(xform.transformBoundingBox(myMeshLayer.extent()))
app.canvas.setCurrentLayer(myMeshLayer)

app.show()
sys.exit(qgs.exec())
```

The final GUI:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I am getting an error - 'QgsMeshLayer' object has no attribute 'renderSettings'. I am following the code that I have provided. I have just added the lines suggested by you  for non-temporal mesh layer with scalar dataset group after layer visibility check.  Can you please suggest why am I getting this error?

Comment: Sorry for the mistyping. Correction: 'renderSettings' --> 'rendererSettings'.

Comment: somehow it is still not working.Not getting the layer on map. After layer visibility check (layer_is_visibile) I have added these few lines.                                                                                              root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
layer_node = root.findLayer(layer)  
parent_group = layer_node.parent()
idx = parent_group.children().index(layer_node)
rendererS = layer.rendererSettings()
rendererS.setActiveScalarDatasetGroup(4)
layer.setRendererSettings(rendererS)

Comment: Have you bridged your layerTreeRoot and mapCanvas by `QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge`? I don't see the pre-code of your program, so I take this as default.

Comment: No I haven't. The full code is what I provided in the question. Can you please elaborate this bridging concept?

Comment: See the new update on my previous answer. Double click on the mesh layer in the layer tree will pop up the renderer settings panel.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Since I have all the layers activated in qgis , I want to get a png format map from this qgis file with all layers in python. By the existing code that I have provided in the question I have got all layers except the mesh layer in the map. Do I need to use qgsmapcanvas? If I get all other layers why not mesh layer? Can you please explain the problem? myMeshLayer = QgsMeshLayer('./data/cairns_fixed_wave.sww','MyMeshLayer','mdal') I have used this line by changing path but still not getting mesh layer on the map.